# Java Temporary File test passes on OSX, fails on Windows

Tags: java, junit, io, cross-platform

I've got a JUnit test that tests a piece of code I've been working on that uses temporary files to perform certain functions. For whatever reason, the test passes on OSX, but fails on Windows 7. To simplify things, I copied the test into a new file, and boiled it down to be as simple as possible while still demonstrating the error.

Basically, I initialize the temporary file by writing a comma separated key-value pair into the file (and then assert that it exists, which it does). Then, I attempt to replace the value of the line, based on the key. `updateValueForKey()` has the boolean "checkOldVal", which, if true, requires that `oldVal` passed in match the one in the file. **This test fails on Windows, and passes on OSX whether this is true or false**

Windows Java version: 1.6.0_45

OSX Java version: 1.6.0_65

The code is as follows:

```
public class SimpleTempFileTest {

ReadWriteLock _fileLock = null;
File _file = null;

public SimpleTempFileTest() {
}

@Test
public void simpleTempFileTest() throws Exception {
    _file = File.createTempFile("testCsv", null);
    _file.deleteOnExit();
    _fileLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        _fileLock.writeLock().lock();
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(_file, true));
        writer.append("foo,bar");
        writer.newLine();
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
        _fileLock.writeLock().unlock();
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(_file));
    String line = br.readLine();
    assertTrue("Unexpected value. Line=" + line, line.equals("foo,bar"));
    assertTrue("Unexpected value. Line=" + line, br.readLine() == null);
    br.close();

    //Fails whether checkOldVal is true or false
    updateValueForKey("foo", "bar", "baz", true);
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(_file));
    line = br.readLine();
    //Everything up to this point passes, but the following assertion fails
    assertTrue("Unexpected value. Line=" + line, line.equals("foo,baz"));
    assertTrue("Unexpected value. Line=" + line, br.readLine() == null);
    br.close();
}

String updateValueForKey(String key, String oldVal, String newVal, boolean checkOldVal) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    File temp = null;
    try {
        _fileLock.writeLock().lock();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(_file));
        temp = File.createTempFile("csvTmp", ".tmp");
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp, true));
        boolean seek = true;
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (seek) {
                String[] nvp = line.split(",");
                System.out.println("nvp[0]=" + nvp[0] + ", nvp[1]=" + nvp[1]);
                if (nvp[0].equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    if (nvp[1].equals(oldVal) || !checkOldVal) {
                        String lineToWrite = key + "," + newVal;
                        System.out.println("Writing " + lineToWrite);
                        writer.write(lineToWrite);
                        writer.newLine();
                        seek = false;
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Failed for " + key + ". Val incorrect.");
                        return "Password incorrect";
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.write(line);
            writer.newLine();
        }
        _file.delete();
        temp.renameTo(_file);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
        if (temp != null) {
            temp.delete();
        }
        _fileLock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas guys? Thanks.

Comment: Did you think about, you know, maybe putting it into a debugger and, I don't know, debugging it?

Comment: @rcook The fact that the test passes on OSX, but fails without any throwables on Windows isn't sufficient to you? What would you recommend I look for in the debug session?

Comment: The assert fails.  I would assume that means the line in question does not have the value you expect.  So what value does it have?  What code was responsible for writing that line, and what did it write?  Are there differences in line comparison that need to be checked on?  Debugging is a way to get detail about why something is failing, saving you (and everyone) from just staring at the code hoping something will occur to them.

Comment: @rcook while I respect that the farthest you were willing to go to help me was to downvote me and complain, I gave a full, compilable code example that required no external dependencies. Paste it into a Modern-day IDE, Organize your imports, run it...whatever, you've managed to make me mad. Thanks a ton

Comment: The small, executable example was appreciated, and perhaps I should have skipped the downvote since that such an example is desirable.  But you also just put out a block of code and said "What's wrong with this?".  You are asking for help, I want to see what reasonable efforts you have made to solve the problem yourself.  I am done taking "What's wrong with this" questions, no error messages, no indication that debugging has been attempted, and putting them into my own environment to debug -- too often the OP has left out something vital.   And I notice you got no other comments or answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to differences between the way Windows and Unix handle locks on files. On Unix, One process can be writing to a file, and another can open it to read it. Windows does not allow this.

Full disclosure: I expected Java to throw an IOException if it failed to perform IO-type stuff on files, briefly forgetting that many of those operations return boolean specifying whether or not the operation was successful.

Long story short, near the end of updateValueForKey(), where I delete _file, and rename tmp to _file, temp still has a FileWriter open against it, and _file still has a BufferedReader open against it. Basically, I had to move the _file.delete and temp.renameTo() below the finally block.